# symfony + fosrest: how to validate route param

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I have several actions with same route param, for example

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/api/ip/{ip}", name="app_ip_get")
 */
public function ipGetAction(DocumentManager $documentManager, $ip)
```

How i can to create one `ip validator` and use it everywhere ?
Сan this be done only with forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would create a [Value Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) called `IpAddress`:

```
final class IpAddress
{
    private $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        if (inet_pton($value) === false) {
            throw new \LogicException('Invalid IPv4/6 address');
        }

        $this->value = (string)$value;
    }

    public function getAddress(): string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->getAddress();
    }
}
```

and create custom [param converter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter) which would load this value object based on the request:

```
/**
 * @Rest\Get("/api/ip/{ip}", name="app_ip_get")
 */
public function ipGetAction(DocumentManager $documentManager, IpAddress $ip)
```

In the param converter simply catch the exception when creating the address and if one is catched, rethrow the [BadRequestHttpException](https://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception/BadRequestHttpException.html) which will get handled by the framework. Embrace proper OOP and stop this [primitive obsession](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/25/DesignSmellPrimitiveObsession/) maddness :)

Comment: Thanks! In my free time I started making the symfony bundle based on ObjectValue ideology https://github.com/TheHett/SymfonyValueObjectsBundle